# Split double-columns into separate columns and merge same-named columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, tidyverse, purrr

This has been a tricky problem for which I am really excited to hear solutions.
I have what I call "double-columns", i.e. columns of which the content can be split into two separate columns.

This is my input:

```
structure(list(`A1-A2` = c(2, 1, 1), `A1-A3` = c(2, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `A1-A2` `A1-A3`
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1       2       2
2       1       1
3       1       2
```

For one column, I can demonstrate what I want to do, but not for several:

```
data %>% 
  separate(`A1-A2`, into = c("A1", "A2"), sep = ":") %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c(1:2), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(A2 = A1 -1) %>% 
  mutate(A1 = ifelse(A1 == 2, 0, A1))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     A1    A2 `A1-A3`
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     0     1       2
2     1     0       1
3     1     0       2
```

- This splits the `A1-A2` column into two separate columns A1 and A2.
- If its value was 1, sets 1 into the left column (A1)
- If its value was 2, sets 1 into the right column (A2)
  This only works, as you can see in the code above, for splitting 1 double-column.

The resulting table should finally aggregate all winning scores for each column like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     A1    A2    A3
1     3     1     2
```

Two challenges:

1. How formulate my code in a generic format for any number of double-columns?
2. How can you avoid problems because several split columns have the same name (e.g. when the double-columns `A1-A2, A1-A3, A2-A3` are split, they will have `A1, A2, A3` occurring twice)??

Approaches in `tidyverse (purrr::map)` are preferred, but I am open to other solutions.

Tricky, isn't it?

Comment: And I am sorry, I would have loved to give you more credit but did mention you in the solution

Comment: It's. okay.  I guess you have the solution now.  All. is well then

Comment: Again 1000 thanks for your help, @akrun - You are the best!

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

I put together this solution helped by @akrun who inspired to use  `pivot_longer` and `mutate` with `case_when`. If anybody has a more elegant or shorter solution, please post!

```
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `A1-A2` `A1-A3`
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1       2       2
2       1       1
3       1       2

comparisons <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  separate(name, c("V1", "V2"), sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(win = case_when(value == 2 ~ V2, TRUE ~ V1)) %>% 
  select(-value) %T>% print 

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  V1    V2    win  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A1    A2    A2   
2 A1    A3    A3   
3 A1    A2    A1   
4 A1    A3    A1   
5 A1    A2    A1   
6 A1    A3    A3  

scores <- comparisons %>% 
  group_by(win) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = win, values_from = n) %T>% print 


# A tibble: 1 x 3
     A1    A2    A3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     3     1     2
```